# Kotlin with Intellij doesn't show non ascii characters

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

When I try to print a special character like "ä, ö, ü, á, é, etc..." with

```
fun main() {
    println("ä")
}
```

Intellij outputs:

```
>Task :FirsttryKt.main()
�
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
...
```

How can I print the "ä" or other non ascii characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [known bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-219115).

As a workaround you can add `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` in Help | Edit Custom VM Options and restart IntelliJ IDEA.